# App version showing as 0.0 (0.0.0.1) during local debug

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I am trying to to debug why I get the error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array Exception with TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext

I have downloaded the latest version of the code and the tool is also up to date. I have made sure the config files have an updated 'Version' hardcoded to and that the debugger points to them.

However, during debug, I get the below suggesting that the version I am running is 0.0

```
[11:36:41 INF] Running with args: execute
[11:36:41 INF] OSVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
[11:36:41 INF] Version: 0.0.0.1
[11:36:41 INF] Latest version detected as 11.9.33.0
[11:36:41 WRN] You are currently running version 0.0.0.1 and a newer version (11.9.33.0) is available. You should upgrade now using Chocolatey command 'choco upgrade vsts-sync-migrator' from the command line.
[11:36:41 DBG] Hosting starting
[11:36:42 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[11:36:42 INF] Hosting environment: Production
[11:36:42 INF] Content root path: C:\Users\davidkin\source\repos\azure-devops-migration-tools-master\src\MigrationTools.ConsoleFull\bin\Debug\net472
[11:36:42 INF] Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[11:36:42 DBG] Hosting started
[11:36:42 INF] Config Found, creating engine host
[11:36:42 ERR] The config version 11.9 does not match the current app version 0.0. There may be compatibility issues and we recommend that you generate a new default config and then transfer the settings across.
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix please?

Answer (score 1):

This is the version set within Visual Studio. If you were to download the packaged tool, it would match version 11.9.

Update your version within your configuration.json to 0.0:

```
"Version": "0.0",
```

Comment: Hi Max, I did set my config files to 11.9 as mentioned but I still get the same issue above

Comment: @Davy You'll want to update your config file to 0.0, not 11.9